# Replacing a requirement for TRC10 token with TRC20 on a TRX contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have a contract that allows users to buy a token and pay with a TRC10 token deployed on Tron. Is it possible to replace the token ID with a TRC20 address instead? And if so, how do I implement it? Thanks.

```
 function buy(address _referredBy) public payable returns (uint256) {
    require(msg.tokenid==1234567);//this is the tokenid I want to replace.
    purchaseTokens(msg.tokenvalue, _referredBy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TRC20 uses the exact same spec as Ethereum's ERC20.  Transfers are certainly possible, but it works differently than TRC10.  The user calls `approve` on the token contract and then your contract is allowed to transfer funds on their behalf.  So instead of sending tokens when `buy` is called, the contract goes and gets them.

Hope that makes a little sense.  I recommend taking a look at Ethereum's token page, they go into a lot of detail: https://ethereum.org/token